# Error in the gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How do I fix this error?

This error occurs during the sync of the project.

This happened after the automatic loading of some packages

> Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.registerTransform(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/gradle/api/Action;)V'.

Comment: post the full code and write something about error

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Change the dependencies to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.+'
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU MAN , u saved my life. Stack today with this error too.  Cant understand whats wrong - one project not working, other projects works.